# Has problem in Installing PyDev into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I tried to install PyDev into Eclipse, when I tried to install new software with this site : http://www.pydev.org/update, it complains unable to read repository. I tried to go the page
http://www.pydev.org/update and click the links on this page, it returns 404 page error. Does anybody why? How can I install PyDev into Eclipse?

Thanks,
Josephine

Comment: It's [`https://www.pydev.org/updates/`](https://www.pydev.org/updates/) ending with `s`.

Comment: Same error, Unable to read repository? I tried to go to the page in the browser, it returns 404

Comment: `https://www.pydev.org/updates/` is working for me... maybe there was some hiccup in the network when you tried?

Comment: @user7087799 In the browser, can you access [`https://www.pydev.org/updates/compositeContent.xml`](https://www.pydev.org/updates/compositeContent.xml)? Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: In the browser, the page https://www.pydev.org/updates/compositeContent.xml shows nothing. What do you mean by behind a proxy, what should I do with the proxy? Thanks, Josephine

Comment: Why not install it from the Eclipse Marketplace? They have v8.3.0 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/releases/download/pydev_8_3_0/ is where it links today, and that link goes to a 404 error page...

Comment: please try to answer. if you also had an issue please add a comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue - fails trying in install via Marketplace.  The links all 404 error.  In the PyDev installation troubleshooting (https://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html), it mentions:

**Unable to load repository**

While most times things work as explained, some users may have messages such as:

Unable to load the repository http://pydev.org/updates

Unknown Host: http://pydev.org/updates/content.xml

This means there's some issue accessing the update site in your current connection.

In that case, you can try using a direct URL for the download (all the http://pydev.org/updates/ URLs are actually redirects to the final location). Currently, those redirects point to links on http://bintray.com, so, you can visit the related update site page (such as http://pydev.org/updates) in a browser and see to where it's being redirected (you may want to try that direct link with http or https to see if it makes a difference in your use case).

If they **ARE** redirecting to Bintray, it has been sunset according to JFrog:  https://bintray.com

That said, I was able to install PyDev manually using the ZIP on SourceForge:  https://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/pydev/

Download and extract the zip, then copy the entire folder to the Eclipse 'dropins' dir (not 'plugins').  On Mac OS, open the Eclipse.app package contents, then copy the unzipped dir, and you should end up with:

```
Eclipse.app
  Contents
    Eclipse
      dropins
        PyDev
          features
          plugins
```

Then launch Eclipse.  Rather than using Finder, I launched it from Terminal w/ the -clean option to try to refresh the installed plugins:

```
/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse -clean
```

I didn't see "PyDev" in the toolbar like I'm used to, but PyDev is in Eclipse Preferences, so I set PyDev > Debug > Remote debugger server activation="Start when the plugins is started", and relaunched Eclipse.  So far, so good...

Answer (score 0):

I had to use this mirror https://pydev-11-0-0.surge.sh
......